# What is a syntax for generating the Unicode hexadecimal value of a character in Julia as a `String`?

Tags: string, unicode, julia, hex, codepoint

What is a syntax for generating the Unicode hexadecimal value of a character in Julia as a `String`?

To generate the Unicode hexadecimal value of a character `<char>` as a `UInt32`, one can execute `codepoint('<char>')`.

Example

```
julia> codepoint('α')
0x000003b1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codepoint of a character `<char>`, in hexadecimal integer representation, as a `String` type, can be found by `string(Int('<char>'), base=16)`.

Example

```
julia> string(Int('α'), base=16)
"3b1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure I understand the question. But the following might be relevant:

`\u3B1` is a unicode literal character with codepoint 0x3B1. This codepoint is for α. Entering '\u3B1' produces the α in the parsed string.

So perhaps:

```
julia> string(codepoint('α'); base=16)
"3b1"
```

could help in writing:

```
julia> "\\u"*string(codepoint('α'); base=16)
"\\u3b1"
```

which prints as:

```
julia> print("\\u"*string(codepoint('α'); base=16))
\u3b1
```

and can be copy pasted into a string (with the double backslash), which will later be parsed in to α, as shown by:

```
julia> Meta.parse( "'\\u"*string(codepoint('α'); base=16)*"'")
'α': Unicode U+03B1 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
```